# How to average multiple rows across 12 months

Tags: r

I have a dataset containing monthly data for 20 'buffers' (among other things).

I want to calculate an average for each buffer across all 12 months.

An extract of my data:

```
structure(list(buffer = c(100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 
700L, 800L, 900L, 1000L, 1100L, 1200L, 1300L, 1400L, 1500L, 1600L, 
1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 700L, 
800L, 900L, 1000L, 1100L, 1200L, 1300L, 1400L, 1500L, 1600L, 
1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 700L, 
800L, 900L, 1000L, 1100L, 1200L, 1300L, 1400L, 1500L, 1600L, 
1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 700L, 
800L, 900L, 1000L, 1100L, 1200L, 1300L, 1400L, 1500L, 1600L, 
1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 700L, 
800L, 900L, 1000L, 1100L, 1200L, 1300L, 1400L, 1500L, 1600L, 
1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 700L, 
800L, 900L, 1000L, 1100L, 1200L, 1300L, 1400L, 1500L, 1600L, 
1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 700L, 
800L, 900L, 1000L, 1100L, 1200L, 1300L, 1400L, 1500L, 1600L, 
1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 700L, 
800L, 900L, 1000L, 1100L, 1200L, 1300L, 1400L, 1500L, 1600L, 
1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 700L, 
800L, 900L, 1000L, 1100L, 1200L, 1300L, 1400L, 1500L, 1600L, 
1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 700L, 
800L, 900L, 1000L, 1100L, 1200L, 1300L, 1400L, 1500L, 1600L, 
1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 700L, 
800L, 900L, 1000L, 1100L, 1200L, 1300L, 1400L, 1500L, 1600L, 
1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 700L, 
800L, 900L, 1000L, 1100L, 1200L, 1300L, 1400L, 1500L, 1600L, 
1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 700L, 
800L, 900L, 1000L, 1100L, 1200L, 1300L, 1400L, 1500L, 1600L, 
1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 700L, 
800L, 900L, 1000L, 1100L, 1200L, 1300L, 1400L, 1500L, 1600L, 
1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 700L, 
800L, 900L, 1000L, 1100L, 1200L, 1300L, 1400L, 1500L, 1600L, 
1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 700L, 
800L, 900L, 1000L, 1100L, 1200L, 1300L, 1400L, 1500L, 1600L, 
1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 700L, 
800L, 900L, 1000L, 1100L, 1200L, 1300L, 1400L, 1500L, 1600L, 
1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 700L, 
800L, 900L, 1000L, 1100L, 1200L, 1300L, 1400L, 1500L, 1600L, 
1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 700L, 
800L, 900L, 1000L, 1100L, 1200L, 1300L, 1400L, 1500L, 1600L, 
1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 700L, 
800L, 900L, 1000L, 1100L, 1200L, 1300L, 1400L, 1500L, 1600L, 
1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 700L, 
800L, 900L, 1000L, 1100L, 1200L, 1300L, 1400L, 1500L, 1600L, 
1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 700L, 
800L, 900L, 1000L, 1100L, 1200L, 1300L, 1400L, 1500L, 1600L, 
1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 700L, 
800L, 900L, 1000L, 1100L, 1200L, 1300L, 1400L, 1500L, 1600L, 
1700L, 1800L, 1900L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 600L, 700L, 
800L, 900L, 1000L, 1100L, 1200L, 1300L, 1400L, 1500L, 1600L, 
1700L, 1800L, 1900L), date = structure(c(15984, 15984, 15984, 
15984, 15984, 15984, 15984, 15984, 15984, 15984, 15984, 15984, 
15984, 15984, 15984, 15984, 15984, 15984, 15984, 16000, 16000, 
16000, 16000, 16000, 16000, 16000, 16000, 16000, 16000, 16000, 
16000, 16000, 16000, 16000, 16000, 16000, 16000, 16000, 16064, 
16064, 16064, 16064, 16064, 16064, 16064, 16064, 16064, 16064, 
16064, 16064, 16064, 16064, 16064, 16064, 16064, 16064, 16064, 
16080, 16080, 16080, 16080, 16080, 16080, 16080, 16080, 16080, 
16080, 16080, 16080, 16080, 16080, 16080, 16080, 16080, 16080, 
16080, 16112, 16112, 16112, 16112, 16112, 16112, 16112, 16112, 
16112, 16112, 16112, 16112, 16112, 16112, 16112, 16112, 16112, 
16112, 16112, 16144, 16144, 16144, 16144, 16144, 16144, 16144, 
16144, 16144, 16144, 16144, 16144, 16144, 16144, 16144, 16144, 
16144, 16144, 16144, 16176, 16176, 16176, 16176, 16176, 16176, 
16176, 16176, 16176, 16176, 16176, 16176, 16176, 16176, 16176, 
16176, 16176, 16176, 16176, 16192, 16192, 16192, 16192, 16192, 
16192, 16192, 16192, 16192, 16192, 16192, 16192, 16192, 16192, 
16192, 16192, 16192, 16192, 16192, 16240, 16240, 16240, 16240, 
16240, 16240, 16240, 16240, 16240, 16240, 16240, 16240, 16240, 
16240, 16240, 16240, 16240, 16240, 16240, 16272, 16272, 16272, 
16272, 16272, 16272, 16272, 16272, 16272, 16272, 16272, 16272, 
16272, 16272, 16272, 16272, 16272, 16272, 16272, 16304, 16304, 
16304, 16304, 16304, 16304, 16304, 16304, 16304, 16304, 16304, 
16304, 16304, 16304, 16304, 16304, 16304, 16304, 16304, 16336, 
16336, 16336, 16336, 16336, 16336, 16336, 16336, 16336, 16336, 
16336, 16336, 16336, 16336, 16336, 16336, 16336, 16336, 16336, 
17120, 17120, 17120, 17120, 17120, 17120, 17120, 17120, 17120, 
17120, 17120, 17120, 17120, 17120, 17120, 17120, 17120, 17120, 
17120, 17152, 17152, 17152, 17152, 17152, 17152, 17152, 17152, 
17152, 17152, 17152, 17152, 17152, 17152, 17152, 17152, 17152, 
17152, 17152, 17184, 17184, 17184, 17184, 17184, 17184, 17184, 
17184, 17184, 17184, 17184, 17184, 17184, 17184, 17184, 17184, 
17184, 17184, 17184, 17223, 17223, 17223, 17223, 17223, 17223, 
17223, 17223, 17223, 17223, 17223, 17223, 17223, 17223, 17223, 
17223, 17223, 17223, 17223, 17232, 17232, 17232, 17232, 17232, 
17232, 17232, 17232, 17232, 17232, 17232, 17232, 17232, 17232, 
17232, 17232, 17232, 17232, 17232, 17264, 17264, 17264, 17264, 
17264, 17264, 17264, 17264, 17264, 17264, 17264, 17264, 17264, 
17264, 17264, 17264, 17264, 17264, 17264, 17312, 17312, 17312, 
17312, 17312, 17312, 17312, 17312, 17312, 17312, 17312, 17312, 
17312, 17312, 17312, 17312, 17312, 17312, 17312, 17328, 17328, 
17328, 17328, 17328, 17328, 17328, 17328, 17328, 17328, 17328, 
17328, 17328, 17328, 17328, 17328, 17328, 17328, 17328, 17360, 
17360, 17360, 17360, 17360, 17360, 17360, 17360, 17360, 17360, 
17360, 17360, 17360, 17360, 17360, 17360, 17360, 17360, 17360, 
17392, 17392, 17392, 17392, 17392, 17392, 17392, 17392, 17392, 
17392, 17392, 17392, 17392, 17392, 17392, 17392, 17392, 17392, 
17392, 17424, 17424, 17424, 17424, 17424, 17424, 17424, 17424, 
17424, 17424, 17424, 17424, 17424, 17424, 17424, 17424, 17424, 
17424, 17424, 17456, 17456, 17456, 17456, 17456, 17456, 17456, 
17456, 17456, 17456, 17456, 17456, 17456, 17456, 17456, 17456, 
17456, 17456, 17456), class = "Date"), mean = c(1.215838882, 
1.088822109, 0.989531359, 0.823662403, 0.711081399, 0.538787295, 
0.433376764, 0.264958626, 0.25004379, 0.470761656, 0.388691884, 
0.098983408, 0.2033786, 0.186319853, 0.316626707, 0.384678207, 
0.151754468, 0.021208597, 0.070374404, 1.642164596, 1.5240609, 
1.356737414, 1.138406446, 0.989445483, 0.775460764, 0.64431253, 
0.457905314, 0.403775943, 0.520688199, 0.370364428, 0.147411867, 
0.177712147, 0.175085484, 0.237685702, 0.318550327, 0.165086768, 
0.047179424, 0.083480265, 0.959871169, 0.861126848, 0.715940454, 
0.55645199, 0.42624073, 0.274809049, 0.1777997, 0.084744839, 
0.054235277, 0.143284816, 0.094401748, 0.013418036, 0.02932515, 
0.016985843, 0.033923091, 0.109454413, 0.079167565, 0.011850503, 
0.015270404, 1.115561879, 1.118547733, 1.008445249, 0.807292202, 
0.619912547, 0.279178175, 0.139024045, 0.012907406, -0.009447278, 
0.049632182, 0.00678033, -0.092529329, -0.012337128, 0.033859182, 
0.081019116, 0.107821823, 0.008842851, -0.011484568, 0.037363486, 
1.186130896, 1.021365666, 0.857613199, 0.643899541, 0.477285226, 
0.308509163, 0.255213401, 0.117960822, 0.124952278, 0.293408528, 
0.217805546, -0.025199489, 0.004961657, 0.02917934, 0.129920121, 
0.236894044, 0.079171313, -0.043470064, 0.006356774, 1.64361703, 
1.54039779, 1.411086458, 1.236237665, 1.066643799, 0.766247715, 
0.633964581, 0.468390994, 0.450625728, 0.599879161, 0.470545048, 
0.231224345, 0.266935106, 0.243939704, 0.361542188, 0.472305981, 
0.21139414, 0.062885848, 0.070500871, 2.303472759, 2.157337917, 
1.969416805, 1.742266165, 1.536159994, 1.251516299, 1.066625294, 
0.775546646, 0.66155575, 0.808701489, 0.656754134, 0.332386128, 
0.410712469, 0.394033103, 0.513500572, 0.600072554, 0.335750906, 
0.113518036, 0.129407806, 2.943621788, 2.751945666, 2.458050683, 
2.188826179, 1.956691499, 1.692109995, 1.468835698, 1.168147981, 
1.041755112, 1.226755177, 0.981195245, 0.576804209, 0.685852767, 
0.660669348, 0.775221712, 0.828703129, 0.463769664, 0.15422009, 
0.162982951, 2.554575623, 2.372103254, 2.290408464, 2.054517841, 
1.861615329, 1.592217004, 1.401797377, 1.051598412, 1.002812695, 
1.267668649, 1.115415035, 0.603692868, 0.710852895, 0.705805591, 
0.875490839, 0.916332795, 0.473202815, 0.164548251, 0.133674457, 
2.496432459, 2.405860455, 2.332276626, 2.154314468, 1.931537295, 
1.593605353, 1.35674335, 1.064953145, 0.948308816, 1.117156309, 
0.902296258, 0.499734413, 0.568312216, 0.536336683, 0.646246448, 
0.703519511, 0.360827234, 0.116159248, 0.121843156, -0.193683744, 
-0.150883103, -0.163360656, -0.22786412, -0.257963676, -0.307309721, 
-0.305761362, -0.394724905, -0.407210918, -0.177085124, -0.140428942, 
-0.201550107, -0.019512414, 0.036890416, -0.036720632, -0.010561275, 
-0.016140439, 0.004593684, 0.066561324, 1.380684443, 1.250706119, 
1.173965001, 0.914397036, 0.760097916, 0.509322326, 0.391089492, 
0.164465793, 0.148020166, 0.313878606, 0.154586799, -0.11587368, 
-0.031067692, 0.00211778, 0.203495391, 0.340638935, 0.127880642, 
-0.025747548, 0.033259082, 0.056043885, 0.271880696, 0.292647284, 
0.184580925, 0.104690094, -0.111611973, -0.1701464, -0.265878888, 
-0.275633824, -0.155178802, -0.204414597, -0.319376869, -0.271366792, 
-0.237639718, -0.146844029, -0.035182789, -0.059645122, -0.047620826, 
0.017376059, 1.392743445, 1.417764028, 1.415585906, 1.327725057, 
1.261706787, 1.088591395, 1.012315648, 0.903954473, 0.849904531, 
0.937846514, 0.814444927, 0.642600376, 0.619143953, 0.545698885, 
0.51165879, 0.464725757, 0.290636394, 0.171534375, 0.085728616, 
-0.106535134, -0.00742211, 0.011385109, -0.069584823, -0.11296655, 
-0.249723692, -0.273480409, -0.276303109, -0.226114738, -0.167877177, 
-0.110217493, -0.089293596, -0.101253827, -0.094656478, -0.07174728, 
0.030344275, 0.045722273, 0.013324444, -0.003683338, 2.747240329, 
2.836421225, 2.705051751, 2.526198267, 2.204361162, 1.488168719, 
1.180385927, 0.952864236, 0.803868624, 0.643424534, 0.503747022, 
0.469753831, 0.447443175, 0.336910431, 0.287241996, 0.254510912, 
0.229997111, 0.136083221, 0.062082349, 2.116996183, 2.310411315, 
2.282293682, 2.074499782, 1.915750444, 1.677553698, 1.506378314, 
1.229625557, 1.146444017, 1.226392345, 1.046117019, 0.699447822, 
0.619510061, 0.522634969, 0.61499077, 0.629987256, 0.309672406, 
0.132654223, 0.118852919, 1.282711399, 1.744908103, 1.398968321, 
1.034402073, 0.701381408, 0.118671792, -0.200273726, -0.385770537, 
-0.507956839, -0.517404552, -0.52280134, -0.49241506, -0.383178089, 
-0.345206625, -0.313454904, -0.235689519, -0.14605215, -0.116389156, 
-0.071567936, 2.905459757, 2.976478462, 2.930253766, 2.752992955, 
2.568241121, 2.291361426, 2.070697474, 1.698827001, 1.652046296, 
1.8812795, 1.658990564, 1.150503479, 1.193308549, 1.088186829, 
1.276389399, 1.271844, 0.690707389, 0.320918302, 0.263052932, 
0.163346787, 0.323565285, 0.355617739, 0.299568497, 0.339650405, 
0.30381453, 0.213207318, -0.015656403, 0.016348774, 0.309246444, 
0.252628522, -0.04072425, 0.119878134, 0.202926357, 0.448243018, 
0.651444884, 0.339529504, 0.053395622, 0.059782062, 3.109011659, 
3.293034789, 3.148142518, 2.847359107, 2.620571798, 2.354282192, 
2.154662371, 1.799961345, 1.659077036, 1.779987021, 1.523015934, 
1.007879685, 1.020642289, 0.933913797, 1.050122458, 1.112308875, 
0.708600292, 0.328096844, 0.238061694, 1.471810915, 1.645113526, 
1.651099529, 1.477998942, 1.340008181, 1.084850388, 0.909319795, 
0.662641391, 0.600637409, 0.857133307, 0.612528334, 0.244987389, 
0.365849339, 0.35461597, 0.548239393, 0.652339938, 0.261362181, 
0.08712113, 0.091655186, 3.324442272, 3.368835357, 3.226617548, 
2.959897028, 2.754235554, 2.521647178, 2.327990844, 1.997280721, 
1.940654329, 2.127070455, 1.865786378, 1.305294559, 1.211158642, 
1.05880232, 1.178376533, 1.198792776, 0.708653958, 0.355491786, 
0.257578385, -0.143639278, 0.558572512, 0.007050647, -0.268860295, 
-0.703218426, -1.308560058, -1.085585002, -0.510504714, -0.397561478, 
-0.00358799, 0.085958807, -0.237357804, -0.162937684, -0.127590858, 
0.206757209, 0.432435649, 0.410980363, 0.363155446, 0.092740666
), Month = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), Year = c(2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L), JulianDay = c(279L, 279L, 279L, 279L, 279L, 279L, 
279L, 279L, 279L, 279L, 279L, 279L, 279L, 279L, 279L, 279L, 279L, 
279L, 279L, 295L, 295L, 295L, 295L, 295L, 295L, 295L, 295L, 295L, 
295L, 295L, 295L, 295L, 295L, 295L, 295L, 295L, 295L, 295L, 359L, 
359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 
359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 
74L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 
74L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 
106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 122L, 122L, 
122L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 
122L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 
170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 
170L, 170L, 170L, 202L, 202L, 202L, 202L, 202L, 202L, 202L, 202L, 
202L, 202L, 202L, 202L, 202L, 202L, 202L, 202L, 202L, 202L, 202L, 
234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 
234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 266L, 266L, 266L, 
266L, 266L, 266L, 266L, 266L, 266L, 266L, 266L, 266L, 266L, 266L, 
266L, 266L, 266L, 266L, 266L, 320L, 320L, 320L, 320L, 320L, 320L, 
320L, 320L, 320L, 320L, 320L, 320L, 320L, 320L, 320L, 320L, 320L, 
320L, 320L, 352L, 352L, 352L, 352L, 352L, 352L, 352L, 352L, 352L, 
352L, 352L, 352L, 352L, 352L, 352L, 352L, 352L, 352L, 352L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 
57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 66L, 66L, 
66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 
66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 
98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 146L, 146L, 
146L, 146L, 146L, 146L, 146L, 146L, 146L, 146L, 146L, 146L, 146L, 
146L, 146L, 146L, 146L, 146L, 146L, 162L, 162L, 162L, 162L, 162L, 
162L, 162L, 162L, 162L, 162L, 162L, 162L, 162L, 162L, 162L, 162L, 
162L, 162L, 162L, 194L, 194L, 194L, 194L, 194L, 194L, 194L, 194L, 
194L, 194L, 194L, 194L, 194L, 194L, 194L, 194L, 194L, 194L, 194L, 
226L, 226L, 226L, 226L, 226L, 226L, 226L, 226L, 226L, 226L, 226L, 
226L, 226L, 226L, 226L, 226L, 226L, 226L, 226L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 
258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 
258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 258L, 290L, 290L, 290L, 290L, 290L, 290L, 
290L, 290L, 290L, 290L, 290L, 290L, 290L, 290L, 290L, 290L, 290L, 
290L, 290L), TimePeriod = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), levels = c("1", "2"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-456L), class = "data.frame")
```

I've tried using rowSums(), mutating, group_by(), and tapply() but the more I try the more confused I get.  It'd be quicker for me to export a CSV and do it in Excel, but I'd like to know how to do it in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df |>
  dplyr::reframe(
    yearly_mean_buffer = mean(mean, na.rm = TRUE),
    .by = c(buffer, Year)
  )
#>    buffer Year yearly_mean_buffer
#> 1     100 2013         1.27262488
#> 2     200 2013         1.15800329
#> 3     300 2013         1.02073641
#> 4     400 2013         0.83950695
#> 5     500 2013         0.70892254
#> 6     600 2013         0.52968570
#> 7     700 2013         0.41849633
#> 8     800 2013         0.26920293
#> 9     900 2013         0.23601834
#> 10   1000 2013         0.37824489
#> 11   1100 2013         0.28448602
#> 12   1200 2013         0.08660444
#> 13   1300 2013         0.13680530
#> 14   1400 2013         0.12613039
#> 15   1500 2013         0.19607850
#> 16   1600 2013         0.27089432
#> 17   1700 2013         0.13200293
#> 18   1800 2013         0.02674617
#> 19   1900 2013         0.05637502
#> 20    100 2014         1.71449035
#> 21    200 2014         1.60748683
#> 22    300 2014         1.48198909
#> 23    400 2014         1.27932078
#> 24    500 2014         1.10577555
#> 25    600 2014         0.85393292
#> 26    700 2014         0.71194799
#> 27    800 2014         0.49213848
#> 28    900 2014         0.44015248
#> 29   1000 2014         0.61111055
#> 30   1100 2014         0.48499438
#> 31   1200 2014         0.20096548
#> 32   1300 2014         0.28718999
#> 33   1400 2014         0.29364791
#> 34   1500 2014         0.39441286
#> 35   1600 2014         0.46619194
#> 36   1700 2014         0.22718879
#> 37   1800 2014         0.05946922
#> 38   1900 2014         0.08466110
#> 39    100 2016         0.72439367
#> 40    200 2016         0.84482236
#> 41    300 2016         0.85411660
#> 42    400 2016         0.75615299
#> 43    500 2016         0.68319844
#> 44    600 2016         0.48848971
#> 45    700 2016         0.42108462
#> 46    800 2016         0.31903779
#> 47    900 2016         0.28713535
#> 48   1000 2016         0.39133386
#> 49   1100 2016         0.30501517
#> 50   1200 2016         0.16161175
#> 51   1300 2016         0.17388858
#> 52   1400 2016         0.15402958
#> 53   1500 2016         0.18240738
#> 54   1600 2016         0.21477148
#> 55   1700 2016         0.11549564
#> 56   1800 2016         0.06195677
#> 57   1900 2016         0.05155234
#> 58    100 2017         1.68708449
#> 59    200 2017         1.90499185
#> 60    300 2017         1.77164806
#> 61    400 2017         1.56344715
#> 62    500 2017         1.36280151
#> 63    600 2017         1.02820662
#> 64    700 2017         0.88033029
#> 65    800 2017         0.71529655
#> 66    900 2017         0.66874434
#> 67   1000 2017         0.81356639
#> 68   1100 2017         0.69157537
#> 69   1200 2017         0.40180761
#> 70   1300 2017         0.43304206
#> 71   1400 2017         0.39305367
#> 72   1500 2017         0.52251586
#> 73   1600 2017         0.59983190
#> 74   1700 2017         0.35591733
#> 75   1800 2017         0.16738519
#> 76   1900 2017         0.11085549
```

Comment: Thanks - I don't want the year, but I can see how to modify that.